# Importing Excel data to polygon Layer using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, excel, combine

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I have a polygon layer (65 features) saved. My colleague has made an Excel sheet with a number of different columns with different attributes on each feature.

Is there any way to combine both of these without manually inputting the data from the Excel to the shapefile?

Each feature is named and numbered.

Comment: do the two datasets share any common attributes? are the names **exactly** the same?

Comment: What GIS software are you using? This is trivial if both datasets have ID columns with matching values, it's simply a join.

Comment: The names are identical and I could also number both datasets 1-65 to be safe.

Comment: Using ArcGIS Pro but also am somewhat familiar with QGIS. Thank you.

Comment: Add Join, joins tables together but it is in memory, Join Field permanently attaches fields, explore the help file for these tools.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. Saved me a lot of mind numbing time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that one attribute in the shapefile attribute table and Excel file are identical and use the join field tool.

Comment: Your solution would better help others if you added a few screen shots. Show your inputs and the results. Currently this "answer" is just a comment.